# Restrict group or user access per components

Tags: jira

I would like to restrict the visibility of issues by users or groups on the criteria that the issues belong or not to a component. Is it possible or not ? If not I guess that it is a bad design to want to do it, then what would be pertinent ?

Typically a book project : the book is typesetted using so technical tools and the end product is the pdf. There is a `Reviewers` groups of user tasked with correcting typos etc based on reading the pdf. I don't what them to see technical issues about how the pdf is produced etc.

Comment: Would not it be much easier just to use separate JIRA projects for this permission handling?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to set security level by component. It's possible with some coding.

According to [Nic Brough](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Access-permission-based-on-Component/qaq-p/160007) (Atlassian Community Leader) back in 2012 to similar question

> You can't do it directly. There are no permissions for components.
>
> Indirectly, you could try to find or write a plugin that will set a security level based on components.

One year later (2013), a users asked something similar and again [Nic Brough](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-assign-issue-security-based-on-component/qaq-p/348331)

> To actually do "security level set by component", you need to do some coding. You need to find/write a post-function to add to the "create" transtion (or listener if you want to do it on edit actions). The code is a simple "if component X, then set security Y" block of statements. I'd look at using the script runner plugin to do it.

Then, later (in 2014), a different user also wrote about [restricting access based on component](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/jira-restrict-workflow-access-based-on-component/qaq-p/279297)

> I created a Security Level.

Four years later, a different user went back to the 2013's question and explained *how to set security level based on Component*

```
issue.components*.name.contains('Sample')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can share access to a specific board with the filter which meets all your needs. No additional effort required.